# How to intercept functions from those imported external packages by AOP

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, aop

For example, now I want to intercept the method split() of java.lang.String by AOP.

Is it possible?

I have tried some normal methods but it did not work.

```
@Aspect
public class TestAspect {

    @Before ("execution (* java.lang.String.split(..))")
    public void logBeforeString(JoinPoint joinPoint) {  
        System.out.println("SPLIT BEGIN");  
    }

}
```

Below is the configuration file :

```
<!-- Aspect -->
<aop:aspectj-autoproxy />
<beans:bean id="TestAspect" class="com.dong.partner.aspect.TestAspect" />
```

With other pointcuts in my own project, they work well without problems.

So anyone knows how to intercept the imported external packages?

Answer (score 0):

No, nothing in java.lang can be advised using `execution`.  See [this question for a more detailed explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6557966/can-aspectj-add-methods-to-java-lang-string).

> So anyone knows how to intercept the imported external packages?

You're using `<aop:aspectj-autoproxy />` which means that Spring is using proxy based AOP.  Essentially, Spring is creating a wrapper around each of your beans if the bean is advised with AOP.  When a method on one of your beans is called, it hits the proxy/wrapper first.  The proxy decides whether it should invoke your bean directly or whether one or more aspects should be called.

There are [limits to the type of advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21472679/compile-load-time-weaving-with-spring) you can use with proxy based AOP.  To intercept calls *from your code* to non-bean classes you need to switch to compile time or load time weaving with aspectj and use [call pointcuts](https://eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/next/progguide/quick.html#quick-pointcuts) instead of `execution` pointcuts.  The aspectj compiler will rejigger your bytecode so that any calls from your code to java.lang.String are rewritten to invoke the `call` pointcut.

Interestingly, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7808700/how-to-remove-java-calls-while-using-cflow-in-aspectj) had the opposite issue that you're experiencing.

Comment: And BTW, my answer in the other thread about JDK weaving (if you really think you need that) only works with full-blown AspectJ, not with proxy-based "AOP lite" frameworks such as Spring AOP. If you want to intercept anything which is not a Spring bean, use AspectJ - it integrates well with Spring. Then you can use `call()` pointcuts instead of `execution()` and at least capture JDK method calls from your own code.